# wcf service don't want to be added to my asp/silverlight web application

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, silverlight, web-applications

i have an asp application, and want to add some Silverlight look to it, so i added a Silverlight application(control) to my asp project. then i added a wcf service to the asp project, now when adding this wcf service to the Silverlight project it gives me an error. any suggestions?

Comment: the error is (there was an error downloading metadata from the address. please verify that you have entered a valid address).. but the address is correct (http://localhost:2969/Service1.svc)

Comment: Could it be as easy as including "http://" before your address?

Comment: And what kind of web service is it? Some services are not out-of-the-box supported by Silverlight. Like net.tcp

Comment: The "http://" is included.. and it is a wcf service

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that the classes and keywords you have used in the WCF methods, are supported by client-side of the Silverlight application.

Also, have you returned DataTable in any of the methods in the WCF service??
If yes, use list of entities, or DataSet instead of DataTable.

Hope it helps :)

Comment: actually i didn't add any classes nor methods yet

Comment: Have you edited the DoWork method? If yes, have you updated the same change in both svc and Sevice1.cs ??